# Daily error of "The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again."

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, form, service

I'm using Sharepoint 2013, I've searched and found tons of articles about this issue but restarting the SharePoint Search Host Controller does fix the issue and forms can be saved again. My problem is that I have to do this ever day, every morning we get this error and restarting that service fixes the issue (i have that service disabled now as well)

Any thoughts as what the root of the problem could be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this type of the issue basically arise due to Heavy Ram usage by Seach Host Cotroller(noderunner.exe) or if your server is under heavy load.

**Search Host Controller Service**This service manages the search topology components. The service is automatically started on all servers that run search topology components.

So how much Ram you have and how many server in the farm you have?

Possible fixtures are:

- If search component is not running on that server then you can disable this services.
- Change the noderunner.config file and set the max memory for it. use this blog for more understanding and configuration.

http://platinumdogs.me/2014/01/07/controlling-search-noderunner-memory-usage-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Our SQL server have 16GB ram with dual core. Our Sharepoint server has 6GB ram with dual core. We resently migrated sharepoint from 2010 to 2013 at the same time as doing a domain change (not recommended). I disabled the Search Host Controller server on Friday and that seemed to help as most users aren't getting that message now. There is one user in particular that still gets that error.

We've only got about a dozen or more users so I would doubt it being a server resource issue and when I view the task manager ram usage is usually around half.